# Why does my plugin not give a name to the item?

Tags: plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I've tried everything, but with this code, the items I get for killing a player will have their base Minecraft name, why? I've tried everything. Could another plugin be blocking it? What could be the problem?
Java, intellijidea, 1.8 Code:

```java
public class killitem implements Listener {
    private random plugin = random.getPlugin(random.class);

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerDeath(PlayerDeathEvent e) {
        Player player = e.getEntity();
        Player killer = player.getKiller();

        //Enderpearl

        ItemStack is = new ItemStack(Material.ENDER_PEARL);
        ItemMeta meta = is.getItemMeta();
        meta.setDisplayName("" + ChatColor.GOLD + ChatColor.YELLOW + ChatColor.BOLD + "Véggyöngy");
        ArrayList<String> lore = new ArrayList();

        //Blaze rod

        ItemStack is2 = new ItemStack(Material.BLAZE_ROD);
        ItemMeta meta2 = is2.getItemMeta();
        meta.setDisplayName("" + ChatColor.GOLD + ChatColor.DARK_RED + ChatColor.BOLD + "Mentőrúd");
        ArrayList<String> lore2 = new ArrayList();
        lore.add("|" + ChatColor.RED + "Jobb klikk: |" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + " ▪ " + ChatColor.GRAY + "Feltölti " + ChatColor.RED + "teljesen " + ChatColor.GRAY + "az életedet!");
        meta.setLore(lore2);
        is2.setItemMeta(meta2);

        //Csillag

        ItemStack is3 = new ItemStack(Material.NETHER_STAR);
        ItemMeta meta3 = is3.getItemMeta();
        meta.setDisplayName("" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + ChatColor.BOLD + "Második Esély");
        ArrayList<String> lore3 = new ArrayList();
        lore.add("|" + ChatColor.GREEN + "Jobb klikk: |" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + " ▪ " + ChatColor.GRAY + "Feldob " + ChatColor.RED + "60 " + ChatColor.GRAY + "blokk magasra!");
        meta.setLore(lore3);

        //Toll

        ItemStack is4 = new ItemStack(Material.FEATHER);
        ItemMeta meta4 = is4.getItemMeta();
        meta.setDisplayName("" + ChatColor.AQUA + ChatColor.BOLD + "Speed");
        ArrayList<String> lore4 = new ArrayList();
        lore.add("|" + ChatColor.AQUA + "Jobb klikk: |" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + " ▪ " + ChatColor.GRAY + "Speed 4-et kapsz " + ChatColor.AQUA + "10 " + ChatColor.GRAY + "másodpercre!");
        meta.setLore(lore4);

        //Quartz

        ItemStack is5 = new ItemStack(Material.QUARTZ);
        ItemMeta meta5 = is5.getItemMeta();
        meta.setDisplayName("" + ChatColor.RED + ChatColor.BOLD + "Instant Health");
        ArrayList<String> lore5 = new ArrayList();
        lore.add("|" + ChatColor.RED + "Jobb klikk: |" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + " ▪ " + ChatColor.GRAY + "Feltölti " + ChatColor.RED + "teljesen " + ChatColor.GRAY + "az életed!");
        meta.setLore(lore5);

        //Aranyalma

        ItemStack is6 = new ItemStack(Material.GOLDEN_APPLE);
        ItemMeta meta6 = is6.getItemMeta();
        meta.setDisplayName("" + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Aranyalma");
        ArrayList<String> lore6 = new ArrayList();


        int upper = 5;
        Random random = new Random();
        random.nextInt(5 + (upper));
        if (player.isDead()) {
            player.getKiller();

            if (player.getKiller() instanceof Player) {
                random.nextInt(5 + (upper));

                if (random.nextInt(5 + (upper)) == 6) {
                    killer.getInventory().addItem(is2);
                    is2.setItemMeta(meta2);
                } else if (random.nextInt(5 + (upper)) == 7) {
                    killer.getInventory().addItem(is3);
                    is3.setItemMeta(meta3);
                } else if (random.nextInt(5 + (upper)) == 8) {
                    killer.getInventory().addItem(is4);
                    is4.setItemMeta(meta4);
                } else if (random.nextInt(5 + (upper)) == 9) {
                    killer.getInventory().addItem(is);
                    killer.getInventory().addItem(is6);
                    is6.setItemMeta(meta6);
                    is.setItemMeta(meta);
                }
            } else if (random.nextInt(5 + (upper)) == 10) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

okay try to first setItemMeta and then give it

```
if (random.nextInt(5 + (upper)) == 6) {
                is2.setItemMeta(meta2);//like this
                killer.getInventory().addItem(is2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
public class killitem implements Listener {
    private random plugin = random.getPlugin(random.class);

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerDeath(PlayerDeathEvent e) {
        bukkit.getscheduler().runTask(plugin, ()->giveItemForKiller(e));
    }
    
    private void giveItemForKiller(PlayerDeathEvent e) {
        Player player = e.getEntity();
        Player killer = player.getKiller();

        //Enderpearl

        ItemStack is = new ItemStack(Material.ENDER_PEARL);
        ItemMeta meta = is.getItemMeta();
        meta.setDisplayName("" + ChatColor.GOLD + ChatColor.YELLOW + ChatColor.BOLD + "Véggyöngy");
        ArrayList<String> lore = new ArrayList();

        //Blaze rod

        ItemStack is2 = new ItemStack(Material.BLAZE_ROD);
        ItemMeta meta2 = is2.getItemMeta();
        meta.setDisplayName("" + ChatColor.GOLD + ChatColor.DARK_RED + ChatColor.BOLD + "Mentőrúd");
        ArrayList<String> lore2 = new ArrayList();
        lore.add("|" + ChatColor.RED + "Jobb klikk: |" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + " ▪ " + ChatColor.GRAY + "Feltölti " + ChatColor.RED + "teljesen " + ChatColor.GRAY + "az életedet!");
        meta.setLore(lore2);
        is2.setItemMeta(meta2);

        //Csillag

        ItemStack is3 = new ItemStack(Material.NETHER_STAR);
        ItemMeta meta3 = is3.getItemMeta();
        meta.setDisplayName("" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + ChatColor.BOLD + "Második Esély");
        ArrayList<String> lore3 = new ArrayList();
        lore.add("|" + ChatColor.GREEN + "Jobb klikk: |" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + " ▪ " + ChatColor.GRAY + "Feldob " + ChatColor.RED + "60 " + ChatColor.GRAY + "blokk magasra!");
        meta.setLore(lore3);

        //Toll

        ItemStack is4 = new ItemStack(Material.FEATHER);
        ItemMeta meta4 = is4.getItemMeta();
        meta.setDisplayName("" + ChatColor.AQUA + ChatColor.BOLD + "Speed");
        ArrayList<String> lore4 = new ArrayList();
        lore.add("|" + ChatColor.AQUA + "Jobb klikk: |" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + " ▪ " + ChatColor.GRAY + "Speed 4-et kapsz " + ChatColor.AQUA + "10 " + ChatColor.GRAY + "másodpercre!");
        meta.setLore(lore4);

        //Quartz

        ItemStack is5 = new ItemStack(Material.QUARTZ);
        ItemMeta meta5 = is5.getItemMeta();
        meta.setDisplayName("" + ChatColor.RED + ChatColor.BOLD + "Instant Health");
        ArrayList<String> lore5 = new ArrayList();
        lore.add("|" + ChatColor.RED + "Jobb klikk: |" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + " ▪ " + ChatColor.GRAY + "Feltölti " + ChatColor.RED + "teljesen " + ChatColor.GRAY + "az életed!");
        meta.setLore(lore5);

        //Aranyalma

        ItemStack is6 = new ItemStack(Material.GOLDEN_APPLE);
        ItemMeta meta6 = is6.getItemMeta();
        meta.setDisplayName("" + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Aranyalma");
        ArrayList<String> lore6 = new ArrayList();


        int upper = 5;
        Random random = new Random();
        random.nextInt(5 + (upper));
        if (player.isDead()) {
            player.getKiller();

            if (player.getKiller() instanceof Player) {
                random.nextInt(5 + (upper));

                if (random.nextInt(5 + (upper)) == 6) {
                    killer.getInventory().addItem(is2);
                    is2.setItemMeta(meta2);
                } else if (random.nextInt(5 + (upper)) == 7) {
                    killer.getInventory().addItem(is3);
                    is3.setItemMeta(meta3);
                } else if (random.nextInt(5 + (upper)) == 8) {
                    killer.getInventory().addItem(is4);
                    is4.setItemMeta(meta4);
                } else if (random.nextInt(5 + (upper)) == 9) {
                    killer.getInventory().addItem(is);
                    killer.getInventory().addItem(is6);
                    is6.setItemMeta(meta6);
                    is.setItemMeta(meta);
                }
            } else if (random.nextInt(5 + (upper)) == 10) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```